# Calling a REST API on a .NETCore server

Tags: bash, httpie

I am not a linux guru and using curl is too complicated for me. So I found httpie and try to call one of my own REST servers written in C# against .NETCore 2 and running on Docker under CentOS 7.

I have a working Powershell script on Windows and try to port this to a bash script using `httpie`, unfortunately with no luck.

The API generates a file on the server and returns it as `octet-stream`. The headers on the server are defined as follows:

```
        Options = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"X-Api-DocType", filetype},
            {"X-Api-DocLength", responseStream.Length.ToString()}
        };
```

My **POWERSHELL** script (which works fine) looks like so:

```
$request = @{
    Namespace = "MyApplication.MessagingApi"
    Version = "current"
    DataDefinitionLanguage = "Csharp"
    MakePartial = $false
    MakeVirtual = $false
}
$docPath = "D:\Projects\AccountingApiMessageDefinitions.cs"
$Url = "http://172.16.63.241:6083/bbopman/messaging/apireferences"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $Url -Body $request
Set-Content -Path $docPath -Encoding Byte -Value $response.Content
```

I ported this to a `bash` script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://172.16.63.241:6083/bbopman/messaging/apireferences"
request="Namespace=='MyApplication.MessagingApi' Version=='current' DataDefinitionLanguage=='Csharp'"
http -d GET $url $request > ~/AccountingApiMessageDefinitions.cs
```

What I get back is BAD REQUEST but on the server the call is successfully processed. So I guess I make something wrong when reading the response, but don't know what.... Here is the output in my shell:

```
$ ./ExecuteRestCall.sh 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 18:45:50 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.02 NETStandard/.NET
```

Could anybody tell me how I correctly call this from a Linux shell? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes for the parameter values for httpie. Send them without quotes.

```
request="Namespace==MyApplication.MessagingApi Version==current DataDefinitionLanguage==Csharp"
```

Also, you seem to be missing the `MakePartial` and `MakeVirtual` parameters in the shell script version.

By the way: "on the server the call is successfully processed" - this cannot be true. The bad request status is returned by the server, not something that happens on the client.

Comment: I was not debugging it but just looking at the console output. It looked correct but it was in fact wrong: `Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://172.16.63.241:6083/bbopman/messaging/apireferences?Version=%27current%27&Namespace=%27MyAppli...`. The `%27` is the escape code for `'` and that was not there in the PS version... The `MakePartial` and `MakeVirtial` default to `false` if not set, so that is correct. I just needed to remove the quotes and it works! Thanks!